# Can't query JSON using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm using jQuery to grab some JSON data. I've stored it in a variable called "ajaxResponse". I cant pull data points out of it; I'm getting ajaxResponse.blah is not defined. typeof is a string. Thought it should be an object.

```
  var getData = function (url) {
      var ajaxResponse = "";
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "post",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
                ajaxResponse = data;
        }
      });
      return ajaxResponse;
  },
```

...

```
typeof ajaxResponse; // string

ajaxResponse.blah[0].name // ajaxResponse.blah is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you specify option `dataType` = `json`

```
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
            ajaxResponse = data;
    }
  });
```

Comment: How come the type is post? would that be get? Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Q8-coder has the right of it, but to give you some details:  your server is really passing back a string that you've formatted into JSON.  You'll need to tell jQuery what to expect, otherwise it just assumes it received a string.

Add the following to your $.ajax options:

```
dataType: "json"
```

Also, refer to the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) for examples and documentation for these options.